# How to generate JsonSchema As Array from Java Class

Tags: java, jsonschema

I'm generating JsonSchema from Java class using fasterxml.jackson.
The generated Jsonschema will be as below

```
    {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
     }
    }
```

My code to generate JsonSchema

```
public static String getJsonSchema(Class definitionClass) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper().disable(
                MapperFeature.CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS);
        JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(definitionClass);
        JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGen = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
        JsonSchema schema = schemaGen.generateSchema(javaType);
        return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
    }
```

I tried to use `ArraySchema arraySchema = schema.asArraySchema();` but it generates invalid schema.
My expected JsonSchema should be like below

```
  {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR:* Call `getJsonSchema(MyClass[].class)`

---

Works fine if we simply tell it to generate the schema of a Java array.

To demo, I created a `MyClass` class fitting the shown schema. I used `public` fields for simplicity of the demo, but we'd use `private` fields and `public` getter/setter methods in real life.

```java
class MyClass {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

Now, to show that we get the same result as in the question, we call it with `MyClass.class`:

```java
System.out.println(getJsonSchema(MyClass.class));
```

*Output*

```json
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:MyClass",
  "properties" : {
    "id" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, we want the schema to be an array of those, so we will instead call it using `MyClass[].class`.

```java
System.out.println(getJsonSchema(MyClass[].class));
```

*Output*

```json
{
  "type" : "array",
  "items" : {
    "type" : "object",
    "id" : "urn:jsonschema:MyClass",
    "properties" : {
      "id" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above was tested using `jackson-module-jsonSchema-2.10.3.jar`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that the solution was that simple.